# How to auto update field in a saved document

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

How Can I update a field in a saved lotus document every time a user opens it. I want to display what server the user is connected. right now it is displaying the server where the document is created.

Here's the default field value

```
@Name([CN]; @Subset(@DbName; 1))
```

Comment: The code `@Name([CN]; @Subset(@DbName; 1))` returns the server name of the current database. What do mean by _I want to display what server the user is connected_?

Comment: @Naveen Yes it will return the server name of the current Server upon creation of the document and then save it as text. I want it to be every time someone opens the documents it will return the server the user is connected to

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your field to a Computed for Display field. The field will then re-compute its value when opened (but only for display - the value is not stored in the document).

Comment: how about those documents saved before? some implications? Thanks!

Comment: It will work with existing documents too as the Computed for Display field will override the stored value - especially if you change the field name completely.

Comment: Computed for Display fields do not override saved computed fields with the same field name. Changing the name works around that, but if you don't want to change the field name, you can just delete the old saved item from the documents using a simple formula agent: FIELD mySavedField := @DeleteField.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the mask event postopen.

1. Bring the document in edit mode with  @Command([EditDocument]; "1");
2. and then update the field FIELD fieldName := value ;
3. and last save the document again.

Answer (score -2):

Your document should be saved. And your RichtextItem should be updated. After that only the content of the RichText item will be shown.

Set the SaveOptions field as 0. Save the document.
Update the RichText field.